# Retrieving Facebook reports in R

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

**Note:** *this is an updated post*

In Facebook I have scheduled report reports to be sent to my e-mail.
Unfortunately reports are not coming as attachment but rather as a link e.g. below
https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/download_report.php?act=1119884838046520&report_run_id=6086936413420&format=csv&source=email_v2

Please help me to construct the URI path to retrieve the report.

**Current state**

I am able to get properties of the report:

```
RCurl::getURL("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/6087139848020?access_token=EAAX****")
```

results into

```
 $ id                      : chr "6087139848020"
 $ account_id              : chr "1119884838046520"
 $ schedule_id             : chr "6085730147820"
 $ time_ref                : num 1.49e+09
 $ time_completed          : num 1.49e+09
 $ async_status            : chr "Job Completed"
 $ async_percent_completion: num 100
 $ friendly_name           : chr "*****"
 $ date_start              : chr "2017-05-03"
 $ date_stop               : chr "2017-05-03"
```

So everything seems OK

**Problem**

However by trying to access the `/report_ID/insights` as suggested [FB API reference/ad-report-run/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-report-run/):

```
RCurl::getURL("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/6087139848020/insights?access_token=E***")
```

I get an error message:

```
(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting summary field (results)
```

Any ideas how to get the body of Facebook report distributed by e-mail?

Help will be strongly appreciated.

PS Special thanks to [user @phwd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/321505/phwd) for suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is

```
curl -G \
  -d 'report_run_id=6087450841820' \
  -d 'format=csv' \
  'https://www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report/'
```

Source of info: [FB docs for asynchronous reports](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/best-practices/v2.9#asynchronous)